# PostgreSQL regexp_replace() to remove Brackets(Example)

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have addresses like this

```
420 CONSUMER SQUARE (PET SMART PARKING LOT)
```

in a column and I want to remove the brackets and the word in that and the result should look like

```
420 CONSUMER SQUARE
```

How can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 13):

Please try this

`SELECT regexp_replace('420 CONSUMER SQUARE (PET SMART PARKING LOT)', '\(.*\)', '');`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `regexp_replace` function

```
SELECT regexp_replace('420 CONSUMER SQUARE (PET SMART PARKING LOT)', '^(.*)\\(.*?\\)', '\\1')
-- or
SELECT regexp_replace('420 CONSUMER SQUARE (PET SMART PARKING LOT)', '\\(.*?\\)$', '')
```

Both examples will return `420 CONSUMER SQUARE`

Comment: I have lots of this in a column with different address name so where can i put the column name in this ??

Comment: @DeepanKaviarasu `SELECT regexp_replace(address_column_name, '\\(.*?\\)$', '')`

Comment: "SELECT ColumnName, (regexp_replace(ColumnName, '\\(.*?\\)$', '')) from TableName " will this work ??

Comment: 10 NO WHITE HORSE PK (PARKING, New Jersey - What should I do if column has single open bracket like this example ??

Comment: @Vaishali I tested it on the exactly same version (9.3.5). What does it show when you run the query above?